# Cython cdef class doesn't recognize prange

Tags: methods, parallel-processing, cython

I have three arrays **a,b,x** and want to perform a lot of operations over them. **Op(a,b,x)** is the function which make these operations. But the situation isn't just that. The array **x** will be varying a lot, so it will be nice to store **a,b** to save time. Furthermore, once in a while the arrays **a,b** will have to change too. With this in mind I create the following class.

```
cimport numpy as np
from cython.parallel cimport prange
from cython cimport wraparound, boundscheck

cdef class parallel_ops:
    cdef double[:] a 
    cdef double[:] b
    cdef double[:] x

    @boundscheck(False)
    @wraparound(False)
    def __init__(self, double[:] a, double[:] b, double[:] x):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.x = x

    @boundscheck(False)
    @wraparound(False)
    def update(self, double[:] a, double[:] b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @boundscheck(False)
    @wraparound(False)
    cdef double Op(self, double[:] x):
        cdef int i, j, k
        cdef int m = self.a.shape[0]
        cdef int n = self.b.shape[0]
        cdef int p = self.x.shape[0]
        cdef double s = 0.0
        for i in prange(m, nogil=True):
            for j in range(0,n):
                for k in range(0,p):
                    s += self.a[i]**2*self.b[j]**2*self.x[k]**2    
        return s

    @boundscheck(False)
    @wraparound(False)
    def receive_input(self, double[:] x):
        return self.Op(x)
```

The function **Op** is just an example, my original function is much bigger and there is no point showing it here. The point is that everything is working fine, except for the prange part, which is being completely ignored. The function **Op** was supposed to run in parallel but for some reason it is sequential. How can I fix this? And what is going on?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Do you build with openmp flags on?

Comment: @ead I just solved my problem and was exactly what you said. I was using %%cython command via jupyter notebook, but after compiling properly everything worked fine. It is a little strange though. I only "trusted" the notebook compilation because prange for functions were working as expected. For some reason the same doesn't apply for methods.